How can i target the elements of a webpage that have visual impact on the user?
I want to create a list with all the elements of a webpage that have a visual impact on the user, which means i dont want it to conatin the elements that work only as containers for other elements.
To do so, i check if the element contains visible text or its media(image, video, audio) and use a recursive function to check also the children of the element. But , what other type of elements should i target in order to have more accurate results?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
